# Email design dark mode, is there a way to write with white text color on a dark background in gmail ios?

Tags: html, css, gmail, html-email, darkmode

I know that it is impossible to target dark mode in gmail ios. But I thought I'd ask if anyone ever solved this problem: I have a background image that is dark. The white text reverts to black during dark mode, and on gmail for ios, nothing I tried worked. I even tried putting a solid background color on top of the image but it didn't take.
If anyone ever found a hack, workaround, idea that worked I'd love to hear it!
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

As per @Nathan's request...

One alternative you can try is to remove any dark flat colours from your image and instead set them in the inline CSS. So say you have an image, but where your text lies over the image the background is a flat colour. Taking that flat colour out of the image and instead making a transparent PNG and setting the dark colour on the wrapping cell, email clients will then analyse the background colour against the text and then the text will render lighter than the background colour.

Originally my client had a multi layered design where initially I had the charcoal and white blocks in one large bg image. In testing - Gmail was difficult, as we all know. So I took the charcoal out and made that block transparent, I then added the charcoal colour as a background colour on the entire block and then you get the result above, even with Gmail's crude dark mode optimisation.

Here is the adapted CSS background declaration:

`style="background:#1A1A1A url('https://sendlanehtml.sendlane.com/images/email/Thh8Gtjf88.png') no-repeat top center;`

The #1A1A1A is the charcoal colour from the original background image. This now being a CSS property Gmail or any other email client can now use to analyse the content and optimise accordingly.

---

Here is how I adapted my background image:

1. original with charcoal / white blocks
2. adapted version with the charcoal removed yet the space it used to
   fill, being preserved as a transparent block.

[image]

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"><head>
    <base target="_blank">
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <xml>
      <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
        <o:AllowPNG />
        <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
      </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    </xml>
    <![endif]-->
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="x-ua-compatible">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
    <meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark">
    
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
    <style type="text/css">
    table {
        border-collapse:collapse !important;
        mso-table-lspace:0pt!important;
        mso-table-rspace:0pt!important;
    }
    h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,a,span,td,strong,li {
        font-family:Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif !important;
    }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
      
    <style type="text/css">
        /* cyrillic-ext */
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Raleway';
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 600;
          src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v17/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyCAIT5lu.woff2) format('woff2');
          unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
        }
        /* cyrillic */
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Raleway';
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 600;
          src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v17/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyCkIT5lu.woff2) format('woff2');
          unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
        }
        /* vietnamese */
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Raleway';
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 600;
          src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v17/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyCIIT5lu.woff2) format('woff2');
          unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
        }
        /* latin-ext */
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Raleway';
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 600;
          src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v17/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyCMIT5lu.woff2) format('woff2');
          unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
        }
        /* latin */
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Raleway';
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 600;
          src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v17/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyC0ITw.woff2) format('woff2');
          unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
        }
        /* cyrillic-ext */
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Raleway';
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 700;
          src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v17/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyCAIT5lu.woff2) format('woff2');
          unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
        }
        /* cyrillic */
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Raleway';
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 700;
          src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v17/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyCkIT5lu.woff2) format('woff2');
          unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
        }
        /* vietnamese */
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Raleway';
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 700;
          src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v17/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyCIIT5lu.woff2) format('woff2');
          unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
        }
        /* latin-ext */
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Raleway';
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 700;
          src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v17/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyCMIT5lu.woff2) format('woff2');
          unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
        }
        /* latin */
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Raleway';
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 700;
          src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v17/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyC0ITw.woff2) format('woff2');
          unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
        }
        /* cyrillic-ext */
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Raleway';
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 800;
          src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v17/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyCAIT5lu.woff2) format('woff2');
          unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
        }
        /* cyrillic */
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Raleway';
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 800;
          src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v17/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyCkIT5lu.woff2) format('woff2');
          unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
        }
        /* vietnamese */
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Raleway';
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 800;
          src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v17/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyCIIT5lu.woff2) format('woff2');
          unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
        }
        /* latin-ext */
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Raleway';
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 800;
          src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v17/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyCMIT5lu.woff2) format('woff2');
          unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
        }
        /* latin */
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Raleway';
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 800;
          src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v17/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyC0ITw.woff2) format('woff2');
          unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
        }
    </style>
      
      
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body { background-color:#ffffff; }
        .ReadMsgBody { width:100%; }
        .ExternalClass { width:100%; }
        * { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }
        a:link, a:visited { color:#193152; }
        .whiteLinks a:link, .whiteLinks a:visited { color:#ffffff!important; }
        table, table td {border-collapse:collapse;}
        a[href^=tel]{ color:inherit; text-decoration:none; }
        @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
          u ~ div { min-width: 100vw !important; }
        }
        
        .button, .button2 { transition:0.2s all linear; }
        .button:hover { color:#1a1a1a!important; background:#ffffff!important; border-color:#ffffff!important; }
        .button2:hover { color:#ffffff!important; background:#1a1a1a!important; border-color:#1a1a1a!important; }
        
        @media only screen and (max-width:600px)  {
            #footerContainer {
                min-width: 100% !important;
                width: 100% !important;
            }
            .responsive .column {
                display: block !important;
                width: 100% !important;
            }
            .responsive .columnImage {
                height: auto !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
            }
            #footerContainer .ql-container {
                padding-left: 20px !important;
                padding-right: 20px !important;
                text-align: center !important;
            }
            
            .deviceWidth { width:100%!important; padding:0; min-width:100%!important; }
            .deviceWidthPadding { width:85%!important; padding:0; min-width:85%!important; }
            
            .background { height:1020px!important; }
        }
        
        @media only screen and (max-width:460px)  {
            .logo { width:180px!important; }
            .title { font-size:24px!important; line-height:1.2!important; }
            .hero-text-padding { padding:55px 0 0 0!important; }
            
            .background { height:990px!important; }
        }
        
        @media only screen and (max-width:360px)  {
            .title { font-size:22px!important; }
            .profile-wrap { width:95px!important; }
            .profile { width:80px!important; }
        }
    </style>
      
      
    <!--<style type="text/css">
        @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
            .go-light { color:#ffffff!important; }
            .go-dark { color:#1a1a1a!important; }
            .go-dark-bg { background-image:none!important; background:none!important; background:#2A2C2E!important; }
        }
    </style>-->
    <title>XXXXXXX</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" style="margin:0; padding:0;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="top" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="deviceWidth" style="width:600px;">
                <tr>
                    <td class="background go-dark-bg" width="600" height="1070" valign="top" style="background:#1A1A1A url('https://sendlanehtml.sendlane.com/images/email/Thh8Gtjf88.png') no-repeat top center; width:600px; height:1070px;">
                    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:1150px;">
                    <v:fill type="tile" src="https://sendlanehtml.sendlane.com/images/email/Thh8Gtjf88.png" color="#1A1A1A" />
                    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                    <![endif]-->
                    <div>
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="deviceWidthPadding" style="width:480px;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="hero-text-padding go-light go-dark-bg" style="font-family:'Raleway', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:11px;line-height:16px;color:#fffffe;font-weight:600;text-align:center; letter-spacing:2px; padding:55px 20px 0 20px; background-color:#1a1a1a;">
                                                FROM THE BLOG

                                                <p class="title go-light" style="margin:10px 0; font-size:29px; line-height:35px; font-weight:800; letter-spacing:0;"><a href="https://www.sendlane.com/blog-posts/essential-segments-for-your-ecommerce-holiday-marketing?utm_medium=email&utm_source=friday-newsletter&utm_campaign=blog" style="text-decoration:none; color:#fffffe;">7 Essential Segments for Your eCommerce Holiday Marketing in 2020</a></p>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" class="go-dark-bg" style="padding:20px 0 35px 0;">
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:separate !important;">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="center">
                                                        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                                        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                        <tr>
                                                        <td align="center" bgcolor="#ff2988" style="padding:5px 15px;" valign="top">
                                                        <![endif]-->
                                                        <a class="button go-dark" href="https://www.sendlane.com/blog-posts/essential-segments-for-your-ecommerce-holiday-marketing?utm_medium=email&utm_source=friday-newsletter&utm_campaign=blog" target="_blank" style="background-color:#ff2988;border-collapse:separate !important;border-top:15px solid #ff2988;border-right:25px solid #ff2988;border-bottom:15px solid #ff2988;border-left:25px solid #ff2988;color:#fffffe;display:inline-block;font-family:'Raleway', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:19px;text-align:center;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none; border-radius:8px;">Start Segmenting</a>
                                                        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                                        </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                        <![endif]-->
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center"><a href="https://www.sendlane.com/blog-posts/essential-segments-for-your-ecommerce-holiday-marketing?utm_medium=email&utm_source=friday-newsletter&utm_campaign=blog"><img src="https://sendlanehtml.sendlane.com/images/email/KKZVa1Hmz0.png" width="480" style="display:block; width:480px; max-width:100%;" border="0" alt="" /></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                    </v:textbox>
                    </v:rect>
                    <![endif]-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Litmus test of Gmail iOS app:

Here you can see Gmail taking what we've defined in HTML/CSS and making a better judgement call on how to proceed for dark mode optimisation.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is great. I am sure many users will love seeing this here on stackoverflow!

Answer (score 2):

[According to Litmus](https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-dark-mode-for-email-marketers/) the Gmail iOS app applies a 'full invert', meaning that they don't even attempt to parse what you have but apply some sort of blanket filter to invert all colours.

However, there is a hack been developed which can work https://www.hteumeuleu.com/2021/fixing-gmail-dark-mode-css-blend-modes/.

Comment: Yeah, not surprised. I just thought I'd ask and see if anyone figured out a secret way haha!

Comment: One alternative you can try is to remove any dark flat colours from your image and instead set them in the inline CSS. So say you have an image, but where your text lies over the image the background is a flat colour. Taking that flat colour out of the image and instead making a transparent PNG and setting the dark colour on the wrapping cell, email clients will then analyse the background colour against the text and then the text will render lighter than the background colour.

Comment: The above method has worked great for me in the past but it does depend on the content of the background image. Obviously if the text is sitting over multi coloured elements in the background image then you're out of luck.

Comment: @Digital_Frankenstein Maybe for email clients that partially invert - but not those like Gmail iOS that do a full invert: yeah?

Comment: Nope - here you go - https://litmus.com/builder/41f27c0. So originally the client had a multi layered design where initially I had the charcoal and white blocks in one large bg image. In testing Gmail was difficult, as we all know. So I took the charcoal out and made that block transparent, I then added the charcoal colour as a background colour on the entire block and then you get the result above, even with Gmail's crude dark mode optimisation. Interesting also that it differs between OSs.

Comment: I have specifically commented out my dark mode CSS, so you can see the original design in the HTML preview, plus as mentioned earlier, Gmail doesn't adhere to that anyway and I didn't include any test cases that do. Obviously this is a simple example but it could help a lot of designs where a background colour is all that it takes to change the way these engines interpret colour palettes. @pitzki, FYI ^

Comment: @Digital_Frankenstein I cannot see the builder via the link. I get an empty litmus web page.

What I couldn't understand was whether the transparent image was set as a background to the table or faked on in the surrounding cells? Like feathered on top and bottom.

Thanks for helping out. You are helping me everywhere this week ha ha

Comment: I tried the transparent PNG and it actually did work for GMAIL, but Windows 10 mail kept the text black.

Comment: Weird, working for me in incognito. So effectively, all you're doing is removing any flat colour from your background image and resave the image as a PNG, so where you've removed the flat colour is then transparent. Then set the flat colour you removed from your background image as the background colour on the same table cell as the image. That way it shows through the transparent parts of your background image.

Comment: @pitzki Your next question after finding Windows Mail not working is what email client is more important to you. Gmail or Windows Mail. For my clients and employer, Gmail wins hands down and it'll be more important that all Gmail email clients have a better dark mode experience as Windows Mail numbers won't be as high. However, this may differ in your case, so it'll be a good idea to look at your reporting to work out which is more important. I'd still think Gmail over Windows Mail any day but I'll leave that to you :)

Comment: @Digital_Frankenstein please put this as an alternative answer, with images and code here rather than on an outside link.

Comment: My client is using the Windows mail personally so it has to work for her. This is a very interesting solution for maybe another client in the future. In the mean time I told them to find different images for backgrounds. I gave them visual samples of what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Yeah, not the end all solution but definitely an alternative that can work for some. Fingers crossed the client can come up with something more dark mode friendly.